# How to turn an MBA on when the power button is not functioning?

Tags: macbook-pro

My MBA power button is not functioning (on or off). I would like to know how to turn it on, in case the MBA is accidentally shut down. I have seen the technician do something inside but it's not open knowledge. Can anyone share their technical experience pls. I am confident I can, given specific steps. Thanks!

Comment: Are you still under warranty?

Comment: Unsure if it still works on current machines, but old Apple (USB) keyboards had a power button on top right.

Comment: out of warranty. thanks for the reply.appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOJVqqf0az0) but be sure it's the same model!

Comment: this is great and just what I needed. Thank you so much! Very helpful. God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you think it is a permanet damage the best option is to replace the keyboard.

If you are not sure it is a permanent damage and before you replace the keyboard consider this:

There is a tiny spring loaded contact under the key cap.

Sometimes (rarely) a food or dirt get stuck in there.

1- Use a air can and blow around it, hoping to blow out the dirt.

or

2- Use a Alcohol (with Computer in OFF mode) soak it, wait for 10-20 minutes.
Use Hair blower and warm it up to evaporate the alcohol (not to hot)

or

3- Buy new and [replace the keyboard](http://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/6820/Replacing+the+MacBook+air+keyboard), it is not a walk in the park but doable. It might cost you aprox $60 for keyboard, and you will need a special screwdriver. Estimated TTC about 2 hours.

Comment: thank you so much for the several options. This gives me more options in getting this issue resolved. I am unsure if it is a permanent damage. So 1 and 2 is worth a try. Before I shed some bucks. God bless you!

Comment: How do you remove key cap? Don't want to experiment. Might damage the delicate key cap, especially the power button. thanks.

Comment: gently :) (sorry it is Greek, but clear what to do) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZfD1yTBCX4

Comment: Thank you! The video is self-explanatory. Now, after I remove the key cap, is there anything else I should be looking for that may be causing the non-function?

Comment: That depends! but since you checked the other answer as completed, I guess you have all your answers.